Postfix: exempt from `reject_unknown_helo_hostname` when the _server_ matches a regexp
I'm using Postfix 3.5.8, and I want given servers matching a regexp (from their reverse DNS lookup) to be exempt from unknown host lookup in their HELO command.
I currently have this (simplified) ruleset in main.cf:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    check_recipient_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/mx_access.cf,

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/senderchecks.regexp,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/allowed_clients.cidr,
    check_client_access regexp:/etc/postfix/locarbl.regexp,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname

So, looking at the rules alone, I see that smtpd_sender_restrictions is holding off the email transmission from a given server at its reject_unknown_helo_hostname with
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx1.domain.com[20.4.18.2]: 450 4.7.1 <SSVBR0369.invalid.host>: Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<sender@domain.com> to=<myself@mymx.org> proto=ESMTP helo=<SSVBR0369.invalid.host>

I hope masking the IPs and real hosts above doesn't affect the interpretation of the result. In this case, mx1.domain.com and domain.com are valid hostnames, yet SSVBR0369.invalid.host is an invalid hostname.
I don't want to add the 20.4.18.2 (hypothetical) IP address to my list of mynetworks as I would be opening relay, besides I'd like to match the server by it reverse lookup address (/.*\.domain\.com$/).
The first thing I thought was, then I add this regexp to /etc/postfix/locarbl.regexp and it should do. Didn't work. The regexp rule that checks against the hostname is in smtpd_client_restrictions and a explicit OK there doesn't seem to affect the smtpd_sender_restrictions, be it because they're simply independent, or the latter restriction is evaluated before the former.
What I tried in locarbl.regexp was:
/.*\.domain\.com$/ OK

Then I thought I could just add another rule right before reject_unknown_helo_hostname. Looking up the alternatives in smtpd_sender_restrictions documentation I see all the checks are performed against the MAIL FROM command/header. Although it would nail the actual problem, there would be no guarantee somebody from, say amazonses.aws.com, couldn't explore this rule. I don't think that'd be safe at all.
So, in summary, what I wanted is:
Can I exempt a given client connecting to my smtpd server from the smtpd_sender_restrictions > reject_unknown_helo_hostname rule by a regexp match against its reverse lookup hostname?

I hope nobody votes this down, because the answer "that worked for me" after a bit more fiddling is at the same time obvious and unexpected.
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
    check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/senderchecks.regexp,
    check_client_access regexp:/etc/postfix/senderclientchecks.regexp,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain

And in the fresh regexp file, I just added:
/.*\.domain\.com$/ OK

I could just use the same locarbl.regexp file but that'd be checking the same tens of rules twice, so maybe the rules in both files are better complimentary than overlapping, right?
Although it looks against what's in postfix documentation, I have tested this down to add restriction - send e-mail - remove restriction - send e-mail, and it deterministically worked, so...
I honestly didn't put too much thought in the logic behind the scenes, so this "works for me".

You probably want to check whether you are (or want to be) enforcing smtpd_helo_required=yes? Because either you do not, then this exemption seems excessive. Or you do, then putting all your rules in just 3 restriction classes while leaving another one empty still seems excessively complex. Your intro sounds like you wanted those clients to only skip the helo/ehlo check, not the sender/reciepient domain one as well..

Hmm you are probably right. I have smtpd_helo_required=no but I can't tell that client not to send its broken helo; and it's been useful over time to pick several unwanted clients, even if not enforced.
"put all rules in 3 restriction classes leaving another empty" I don't get what you mean.
"only helo/ehlo not the sender/recipient domain" I hear you, and you're right. I could use some reordering there; but the exemptions I'm adding (so far) are a just handful trustworthy ones.
